# Is there any mechanism for uploading .AAB updates to Google Play from command line rather than thru a web browser?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-developers-console

For scripting purposes I want to be able to do nightly builds and upload .AAB to my closed testing channel.

Is it possible to do this from a command line or am I stuck using a human to point and click on Google Developer Console?

Comment: Have you looked at [Google Play Developer Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#publishing)

Comment: Well that is really interesting @MorrisonChang. Definitely looks like what I want, never knew it existed. Thanks. Turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For automating uploading/deployment of Android apps, probably as part of a CI/CD system rather than command line, Google provides a [Google Play Developer Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#publishing)

> **Publishing API**
>
> The Google Play Developer Publishing API allows you to automate frequent tasks having to do with app production and distribution. This provides functions similar to those available to a developer through the Play Console, such as:
>
> - Uploading new versions of an app
> - Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
> - Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized text and graphics and multi-device screenshots
>
> Those tasks are performed using the new edits functionality, which take a transactional approach to making changes; you bundle several changes into a single draft edit, then commit the changes all at once. (None of the changes take effect until the edit is committed.)

Documentation does have a [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) section with details on [APKs and tracks](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks). Additionally check [API Usage limitations](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api_usage) as well as [upload requirements](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/upload)

Comment: Google has an [automation toolset](https://fastlane.tools/) that offers an [upload command](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/).